# Query not executing in BigQuery using Python client library on EC2 server

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a BigQuery query using the Python client library on an EC2 server, but the query doesn't seem to be executing. Here's the code I'm using:

```py
def run_bigquery_query_thread(query): 
     print("run_bigquery_query_thread started") 
     # Run the query and get the results 
     query_job = client.query(query) 
     print(query_job) 
     results = query_job.result() 
     return results
```

When I call this function with a valid query, the "run_bigquery_query_thread started" message is printed, but the query doesn't seem to execute because the "query_job" variable doesn't print anything. There are no errors or exceptions thrown. The same code works perfectly fine in Google Colab, but not on my EC2 server. I've checked my BigQuery account and there's no evidence that the query has been executed, and the API monitor also shows nothing.

**UPDATE:**

Added this code :

```py
logging.basicConfig()

logging.getLogger('google.cloud.bigquery').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

And got this error:

```
connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /token
```

I saw this Stuckoverflow Q:
[Query not executing in BigQuery using Python client library on EC2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009082/query-not-executing-in-bigquery-using-python-client-library-on-ec2-server)

And because of that, I downloaded the Google pem file, installed certify and replaced the cacert.pem file with _.googlecode.pem and also added this line of code :

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/home/ec2-user/_.googlecode.pem"
```

**still not worked**

What could be causing this issue and how can I troubleshoot it?